# How to make spa using javascript, jquery and require,js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I 'm trying to make a **single page application(SPA)** using **Require.js**, but I have a problem, which is not how to make the call  ***file.html***  with their respective ***js***. The example is as follows

HTML

```
page1.html
page2.html
page3.html
```

Js

```
events1.js
events2.js
events3.js
```

I would like to know how to call each js in their respective html , and beforehand, namely also if these js files which call is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic structure of a require.js file:

```
`person.js`
define(function() { // <==== don't need require, not importing any module(s)

    // put whatever code you want here
    var obj = {
        name : 'John',
        sayHello: function(){
            console.log('hello ' + this.name);
        }
    };

    // tell the module to return obj, or any other function/object you declared
    return obj;
});
```

You can then use this wherever you want, so if your events2.js wanted to say hello, you would write it like this:

```
`events2.js`
define(function(require) { // <==== NEED require, importing a module

    // notice, there's no .js at the end
    // you can also use ../ for example to get parent directory
    var person = require('./[pathToFile]/person'); 

    person.sayHello(); // hello John
});
```

Require.js has a steep learning curve, as you need to set up the config, which isn't easy especially if you're minifying et al.

Edit:

1. Start with a link in your html to your main.js file

**index.html**

```
<script src="libs/require.js" data-main="main"></script>
```

2. You can put your config in main file to set up short-cuts and other stuff

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths : { 
    jquery : 'libs/jquery',
    jqueryUI : 'libs/jquery-ui',
    etc...
  }
});

require(function() {  
    require(['app'], function(app) { 
    app.init(); // <==== this starts your website build
  });
});
```

3. This is where you build your site

**app.js**

```
define(function(require) {
return {
    init : function() {         
      require('dev/menu').init();
      require('dev/content').init();
      require('dev/otherstuff').init();
    }   
  };
});
```

Comment: how to call this into html file

Comment: Sorry, dev/, is folder, or what is it?

Comment: Replace `dev/` with the path to the folder where your file(s) reside, e.g. `[pathToFile]/menu`, `[pathToFile]/content`, etc

Comment: Thanks, you have a punkler o fiddle ??

Comment: What's a `punkler o fiddle`?

Comment: Sorry, an example in plunker or JSFiddle